# Is there any way to animate offset value of SVG Gradient Stop with CSS alone?

Tags: css, animation, svg, gradient, offset

I have a SVG gradient, and want to animate the stop offset value.

I've tried the <animate> tag in <stop> tag, it works fine on Chrome & etc browsers but IE/Edge.
I've tried [smil.user.js](https://github.com/FakeSmile/FakeSmile), then IE is ok, but Edge still doesn't work.

After a long google search, still can't find any way to solve it.

Sadly, Chrome tell me "SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead."

Web animations use JavaScript to animate elements and it's supported by Edge now, but I don't want to use JavaScript. I can use GASP or other js methods.

CSS animations can animate style attributes, but I've no idea how to animate a dom attribute like "offset" of <stop>.

Is there any way to animate offset value of SVG Gradient Stop with CSS alone?

Thank you for any advances!

```
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-44.0633" y1="130.4958" x2="458.3425" y2="-60.602">
    <stop  offset="0.04" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0">
        <animate attributeName="offset" dur="3s" values="0.04;0.94" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </stop>
    <stop  offset="0.08" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF">
        <animate attributeName="offset" dur="3s" values="0.08;0.98" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </stop>
    <stop  offset="0.10" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0">
        <animate attributeName="offset" dur="3s" values="0.10;1" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </stop>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect x="-94" y="-40.5" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" width="602" height="151"/>
```

This's a [example](http://codepen.io/Larry_Rui/pen/GoPqrV) on CodePen 
Works fine in Chrome, IE11(with smil.user.js), but Edge fails.

Comment: Not as far as I am aware...no.

Comment: Is there any other way? Just let the example works on Edge without javascript?